# Edit the output of wp_widget_rss_output()

Tags: plugin-development, widgets

I want to show rss feed in my dashboard widget, i use this code:

```
wp_widget_rss_output(array(
    'url'           => 'http://www.example.com/',
    'title'         => __( 'Some Title' ),
    'items'         => 1,
    'show_summary'  => 1,
    'show_author'   => 0,
    'show_date'     => 0
));
```

but after the 'show_summary' wordpress addes '[...]'. How do i remove it?

Comment: Of course you can. Check this site. Make sure you put some prefixes in front of the 2 function names to avoid issues with other plugins. http://adamscottcreative.com/add-your-own-news-feed-to-wordpress-dashboard/

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because the wp_widget_rss_output() prints its output. If you don't want to display '[...]' copy that function in your functions.php, rename it and remove the code that adds the '[...]' to the summary. You can also create a plugin with this code thus making independent from your theme.